# Why is my second database table connection not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Heres what im trying to do

I want to get the values of a certain column in the first entry that was made by the client the first time he filled my survey and compare it to the new one

so heres my code

```
<?php
$datCurrent = $_SESSION['question11'];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('esm_quiz', $con);

$countRow = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(code_exp) FROM esm_resultat");

if(mysql_result($countRow, 0) == 2){

$con2 = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('esm_quiz', $con2);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM esm_resultat WHERE code_exp = '$datID' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1,2 ";
$row = mysql_query($SQL, $con2);

echo "nombre de ranger<br/>";
    $oldData = $row['q11'];

    if ($datCurrent > $oldData){

        echo"semaine2 > semaine1<br/>";
        echo "".$datCurrent."<br/>";
        echo $oldData;

    }elseif($datCurrent == $oldData){

            echo"semaine2 = semaine1<br/>";

        }elseif($datCurrent < $oldData){

                echo"semaine2 < semaine1<br/>";
            }           
}
?>
```

Comment: Why you repeating mysql_select_db twice ?

Comment: can't you see your second and first database is same..? There is no any change in connection...both are same

Comment: because i want to use a different sql query

Comment: mysql_query($SQL, $con2); Why did you pass 2 parameters?

Comment: @Cedricle i can't get it..do u know database needs to be connected only once not per query.

Comment: thare is no need for select DB second time

Comment: Idk to be honest im kinda trying something that i have never done sooooooo yeah i would like help :P if you dont mind of course

Comment: the thing is I have to count the number of entry and look at a specific row to do what i want to do

Comment: rofl .. haha ..thats a great attitude .. keep on exploring something new.

Comment: @Cedricle first of all you do not need to repeat yourself for database connection add it on top of the script and thats it..you can use database through out the page...note just on page on which you have added connection code not on other page.

Comment: Just an off topic suggestion. You better start using `mysqli` or `PDO` as the `mysql` extension is deprecated and will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note : `mysql_query()` only accepts 1 paramater. It is different from `mysql_select_db()`*

`mysql_query()` runs or execute your query

`mysql_select_db()` just establish a connection with the particular db being selected.

so to give a clear clarification

You cant use `mysql_query()` to establish a connection into a database while executing a query

*insights: You don`t even need to establish another connection with the same database in order to use different query functions.You can use as many or as different functions for query purposes in one connection only.*

Comment: so could i just do

<?php
$datCurrent = $_SESSION['question11'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('esm_quiz', $con);
$countRow = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(code_exp) FROM esm_resultat");
if(mysql_result($countRow, 0) == 2){
$countRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM esm_resultat WHERE code_exp = '$datID' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1,2 ");
...          
}
?>

Comment: what result do you tend to produce?

Comment: well change the query so i can get $oldData use it for comparison

Comment: $datID = where did this come from?

Comment: it is a session var that is set in another page

Comment: You set it in another page.. You cant use it from different page.. You must set this again in this page to use. Set it just like how you set $datCurrent

Comment: Thx for your help I think i found how to do it because of you

Comment: ur welcome . happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using only one connection but if you need to do it this way try adding a [`$new_link`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) parameter like this for the second connection:

```
$con2 = mysql_connect('localhost','root','',true);
```

If the the two connections' parameters are the same this would distinguish between them.

Comment: Unfortunatly the $oldData isnt being echoed so can I assume that the connection did not work?

Comment: Not necessarily. It might be a sql problem or even a column that does not exist. Is the SQL only returning one row?

Comment: no it says 2 so i know it is seeing all the rows

Comment: What says 2 and what is seeing all the rows?